# How to update object parameter in DAO?

Tags: java, spring, dao

I'm new at Java and trying to understand how MVC architecture goes. *Forgive me if I'm wasting your time*. I wrote a DAO Service, it handles the crud model (get, read, update, delete).

```
   public List<User> getUsers();
   public User getUser(Long userId);
   public void createUser(User user);
   public void updateUser(User user);
   public void delete(Long userId);
}
```

here are my abstract DAO functions.

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        em.merge(user);
    }
```

and the controller:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{userId}", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> update(@PathVariable Long userId, @RequestBody UserDTO user){
        try{
            service.updateUser(user);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException p){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException.InternalServerError u){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

in the service:

```
    @Override
    public void updateUser(UserDTO user) {
        userDAO.updateUser(ApiDTOBuilder.userDTOToUser(user));
    }
```

How can I pass the userId and set the new parameters into the current user object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fetch the User using DAO method. And then you need to set the values to the User entity. As you are using @Transactional, spring will take care of updating the values.

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateUser(Long userId,UserDTO userdto) {

        User user= getUser(userId);
        user.setFirstName(userdto.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(userdto.getLastName())
       }
```

Also if you are not using Spring Boot, then you need to enable transaction management by using

> @EnableTransactionManagement